# Probability System Definition and Random Variable

Tags: probability, random-variables, definition

**Setup**

I'm taking a course on probability and our professor has defined random variables in a way that I'm not so used to, I'm used to the definition of a random variable X, being a function from the sample space into the real numbers. Instead we are given this:

[image]

And then we get random varaibles:

[image]

---

**Usage**

A sample definition using this notation is:

[image]

---

What I don't understand is what a system actually is. From what I can gather a system, is like some sort of function which maps into our sample space. But if that's the case than what would the domain of our system W be?

Another idea I had was that a system is just like a random variable, but it need not map out to the reals, instead just some arbitrary set, and then the random variable maps from that set to the reals.

My hunch is that they are trying to decouple the idea of the random event, and then a random variable which produces a real number from that event, but I'm not entirely sure. If anyone has seen this before and knows formally what a system is could they please explain?

Comment: Ugh. Is this a computer science class?

Comment: Surprisingly not, apparently this is a rigorous Probability I course... @Michael

Comment: In what department?

Comment: Department of Statistical Sciences

Comment: It is like they are trying to rewrite probability theory under an assumption that “samples” can never be correlated.

Comment: "Department of Statistical Sciences". That explains it. If I were you I'd ask that professor if in the exam he is happy with the Kolmogorov axioms for $(\Omega,{\cal F},\mathbb P)$ and the orthodox definition of a random variable. Or if he insists that you sing to him that gospel.

Comment: Would it be best to just move on with the standard definitions and try and not get bogged down in what they're trying to do here?

Comment: Normally yes. Unless you need to pass that exam. Putting the jokes a bid aside: I think it is  a legitimate effort to make probability theory less abstract than just presenting it with Kolmogorov axioms. However, for example [E.T. Jaynes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edwin_Thompson_Jaynes) was for example someone who fiercely objected those axioms.

Comment: If you want to understand probability, you'll need to move forward with the standard definitions, since this presentation is not only goofy, but incorrect. In particular, it says "for any real-valued $g$' and does not mention measurability.

Comment: You can imagine $W$ as a random element equal to the identity function, then $X=g(W)$ makes sense as a random variable since $X(\omega)=g(W(\omega))=g(\omega)$. However you have a fundamental problem treating iid random variables because all of them should be functions of the same sample space, contrary to your class. I think (in your class) you are always supposed to assume all samples lie on a product space, so you will never study non-independent samples.

Comment: Ok, I appreciate the feedback on this, and the explanation of W. I think I am going to move forward and attempt to just do more problems with standard definitions and see if I can understand what's going on in this course. I do have one last question, in this definition: https://i.imgur.com/AVoEyxz.png if X is to a be a random variable (function mapping into R), then would I interpret script X as just R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least the class still uses a sample space $\Omega$ and still talks about functions $g:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ (putting details about sigma algebras aside, these functions $g$ are what everyone else would call random variables).

I think your class wants to view $W$ as a "factory" (or piece of software) that, when repeatedly run, produces (independent) outcomes. It wants to use $W$ as the name of the software, and then use $w_1, w_2, w_3$ as "realizations" from $W$. It defines $X=g(W)$ as a new piece of software that puts the output of the previous software through $g$. So then "realizations" of $X$ are $g(w_1), g(w_2), g(w_3)$.

This view is a significant departure from standard probability theory where there is a single sample space $\Omega$, and the outcome $\omega \in \Omega$ determines the values $X_1(\omega), X_2(\omega), X_3(\omega), ...$ for all random variables $\{X_1, X_2, X_3, \ldots\}$. One way to make this consistent is if you consider the product space
$$\tilde{\Omega} = \underbrace{\Omega \times \Omega \times ... \times \Omega}_{\mbox{$n$ times}}$$
so a single outcome $\omega \in \tilde{\Omega}$ has the form $\omega = (\omega_1, \omega_2, ..., \omega_n)$ and you can define
$$X_i(\omega_1, ..., \omega_n) = g(\omega_i) \quad \forall \omega\in \tilde{\Omega}$$

The trouble with this is that it implicitly assumes all "trials" or "samples" are always independent. You should ask your professor how to handle cases when the $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ random variables can be correlated.

---

Regarding standard definitions I would use this:

- A *measurable space* is a pair $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ where $\Omega$ is a nonempty set and $\mathcal{F}$ is a sigma algebra on $\Omega$.
- A *probability space* is a triplet $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$ where $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ is a measurable space and $P:\mathcal{F}\rightarrow[0,1]$ a function that satisfies the 3 axioms of probability.

Now suppose we have a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$:

1. A *random variable* is a function $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that satisfies
   $$ \{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega)\leq x\} \in \mathcal{F} \quad \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$$
   Equivalently, it can be shown that $X:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a random variable if and only if
   $$ \{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \in B\} \in \mathcal{F} \quad \forall B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$$
   where $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is the standard Borel sigma algebra on $\mathbb{R}$.
2. Given a measurable space $(V, \mathcal{G})$, a *random element* is a function $X:\Omega\rightarrow V$ that satisfies
   $$ \{\omega \in \Omega : X(\omega) \in B\} \in \mathcal{F}\quad \forall B \in \mathcal{G}$$

Under these definitions, a random variable is just a random element on the output measurable space $(V,\mathcal{G})=(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$.

---

For two measurable spaces $(V_1, \mathcal{G}_1)$ and $(V_2, \mathcal{G}_2)$ and two random elements $X:\Omega\rightarrow V_1$ and $Y:\Omega\rightarrow V_2$, we say $X, Y$ are independent if
$$ P[\{X \in A\}\cap \{Y\in B\}]=P[X\in A]P[Y\in B] \quad \forall A \in \mathcal{G}_1, B \in \mathcal{G}_2$$
Some people call random elements "random variables." I suspect your last question on the definition 2.0.1 uses $\mathcal{X}=V_1$ and $\mathcal{Y}=V_2$, ignores the issue of sigma algebras, and if we assume $X, Y$ are real-valued then indeed you can assume $\mathcal{X}=\mathcal{Y}=\mathbb{R}$. Alternatively, perhaps $\mathcal{X}$ is the subset of $\mathbb{R}$ consisting of values that $X$ can take, that is, $\mathcal{X}=\{X(\omega): \omega \in \Omega\}$ (the image of the random variable). Some people use notation $S_X$ for this.

Comment: Thanks for this, I think this really helps me understand it formally. Do you have any recommendations for resources that continue in the fashion you've presented?

Comment: I have typed up a "probability review" for students in my classes and also students who take screening exams. It also has several references to both basic and advanced textbooks. I thought students in my class would like it but they were scared away by it. Maybe someone reading this will like it, maybe not. Typing up these notes was the reason I was interested in your question:  https://ee.usc.edu/stochastic-nets/docs/probability-review.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I think your ideas are correct. As I understand it, it is just a philosophical distinction that makes no difference.

When you consider a random variable $g\colon \Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ as a (measurable) function, you realize that the only thing "random" about values of $g$ is really the values of inputs $\omega\in\Omega$. Mathematically, that is the end of the story; and many people are content to think that the randomness is in the nature of the that abstract probability space $(\Omega,\mathcal{M},\mathbb{P})$. But you can consider the source of randomness to be something else. So instead of accepting that the input values to $g$ are random in nature, your professor thinks of a "mechanism" $W$ that produces random outcomes, and then the function $g$ takes that random outcome and looks at a particular numeric aspect of the outcome.

For example, consider choosing a random person from your math class uniformly randomly. This sample (of size $1$) is going to be different every time. The collection of all samples that can be chosen is denoted $\Omega$. This process of choosing a random person is what your professor denotes $W$, and the actual sample/person that is chosen is what your prof calls $\omega$. The function $g$ takes any particular person and measures his/her height. So maybe $g(\omega)=178$. Note that instead of measuring the height of the chosen person using $g\colon \Omega\to\mathbb{R}$, you could measure their weight using $f\colon\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$, hormone levels using $h\colon\Omega\to \mathbb{R}$, or anything else that is numerical about them. These are all random variables.

In summary, usually we think of the domain of $g$ as the source of randomness, but your professor kicks the can one step down the road and thinks of the domain of $W$ as the source of randomness. So to answer your question, yes, $W$ is a random variable too. And its domain is some abstract probability space $(A,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})$.

$$ (A,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P}) \xrightarrow{W} (\Omega,\mathcal{M}) \xrightarrow{\ g\ }(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{
B}_{\mathbb{R}})\ \ .$$
and since $X:=g\circ W$,
$$(A,\mathcal{A},\mathbb{P})\xrightarrow{\ X\ } (\mathbb{R},\mathcal{
B}_{\mathbb{R}})\ \ .$$